# Type 1 Trapdoor Sampling in LWE

Tags: lattice-crypto, lwe, trapdoor

In the [BGN-like](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/182.pdf) LWE cryptosystem, section $2.2$, we sample a $m \times m$ trapdoor matrix $T$ that is full rank such that $TA = 0 \pmod q$.
Suppose that $q$ is prime so we are in a finite field: if $T$ is full rank, the nullspace of $T$ is trivial, and $A = 0$?
In particular, $T$ can have rank at most $m-n$?

Answer (score 3):

Note that although $A\in \mathbb Z_q^{m\times n}$ we have $T\in \mathbb Z^{m\times m}$. When say that $T$ has full rank, we mean over the integers which does not place any restriction of the number of solutions to $TA=0\pmod q$ (with the obvious coercion of matrix entries into a compatible ring).